# How to Read text from word file of extinction .docx in asp .net core6?

Tags: asp.net, docx

I'm trying to read text from word document then make some edits in this text and save it in a new document file, if the document extinction is .doc every thing works normally, On the other hand, if the document extinction is .docx it's does not work normally the data showing in unreadable format as shown in image below:

[image: image after edit the data]

where the code as shown below:

```
public string EditFile( IFormFile file, string nameOfnewDoc, string str1,string str2)
    {
        var fileName = "";
        var filePath = "";
                               
        if (file != null)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "docs", fileName);
            using (var fileSteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyToAsync(fileSteam);
            }

            string originalFile = filePath;
            string newFile = Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "docs", nameOfnewDoc);
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(originalFile,Encoding.UTF8);

            System.IO.File.Copy(originalFile, newFile + ".doc");
            var newText = text.Replace(str1, str2);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newFile + ".doc", newText);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        }
        return "null";
    }
```

Noted that I don't need to use any external package.

can any one help please?